# Parallel Simulation with Intel TBB in VS2010 using MKL for rng

Tags: visual-studio-2010, random, tbb, montecarlo

I need to find the default probability of a derivative via Monte-Carlo simulation with C++ in VS2010 with Intel TBB and MKL installed and only 1GB of memory.

Let S(t) denote the price of the derivative at time t. The current price is S(0) = 100.

For simplicity, the derivative is defined by (the real derivative is more complex):
With a probability of 99 percent S(t+1) = S(t) * exp(X), with X ~ N(mu=0, sigma=0.01)
With a probability of 1 percent the derivative jumps down to S(t+1) = S(t) * 0.4

If the derivative falls below 10 somewhere in 0 < t <=250 the following happens:
With ha probability of 80 percent the price of the derivative at S(t) is set to 1.5 * S(t) or with a probability of 10 percent we will have a default.

Let's say I need to run at least 10mn simulations of this derivative and count all losses.
Then my simulated default probability is #defaults / 10mn. The serial code somehow looks like:

```
for j = 1 to #simulation/{
    for t = 1 to 250{
        generate S(t+1)
        check if S(t+1) defaults
    }
}
```

How do I parallelize the code?
What is the best strategy for the random number generation? I cannot generate the random numbers of type double a priori, because 10mn * 250 * 2 (at least) = 500mn random number * 8Byte = 4GB.

Is it a good idea to divide the number of simulations into chunks of 10 * number of processors?

```
VSLStreamStatePtr stream[10*#processors];
for i = 1 to 10*#processor{
    vslNewStream( &stream[i], VSL_BRNG_MT2203+i, seed );
}

tbb_parallel_for i = 1 to 10*#processors{
    use stream[i]  for random number generation
    generate    10mn / (10*#processor) * 250     random numbers ~ N(0, 0.01) and store them in a vector.
    generate    10mn / (10*#processor) * 250     random numbers ~ Bernoulli(0.01) and store them in a vector.
    generate    10mn / (10*#processor) * 250     random numbers ~ Bernoulli(0.01) and store them in a vector.
    for j = 1 to #simulation/(10*#processors){
        use 
        for t = 1 to 250{
            generate S(t+1) using the vectors filled with random numbers
            check if S(t+1) defaults
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated...
Matt